# Relationship belongsTo inside belongsTo in CakePhp ORM?

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, orm

Can we setup relation `belongsTo` inside `belongsTo` in cake PHP ORM?

For example *Table A* has relation with *Table B* and *Table B* has relation with *Table C*.

When I try to access *Table A* data it contains *Table B* and fetch all data of *Table B*.

But I also want to fetch data of *Table C* as well with Table B, but *table C* does not have direct relationship with *Table A*.

How can I achieve that using ***CakePhp ORM***?

Comment: What version of CakePHP, and can you share how you're doing this read? It's most definitely easy to do this, but there are different ways and it depends on how you're already doing it.

Comment: I have **"cakephp/cakephp": "3.8.*"**

I am doing like this 


`class TableA extends Table {
    $this->belongsTo('TableB')
      ->setForeignKey('FK')
      ->setProperty('app');

}`


Now I want to access TableC inside class of TableA. Is there any way to do it in this way? Thanks

Comment: That's how you're connecting the tables. How are you reading the data?

Comment: I got it working using contain and dot sign for inner relationship.Thanks